# Is there a Powershell equivalent to JavaScript Console Log?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script, which is calling a third party API and getting some response data back. I'd like to just log the response object to see what exactly is returning. I've tried

```
Write-Host ($item | Format-List | Out-String)
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. The API says it will return JSON but I'm not sure how to verify the return at all.

Full script is something like this.

```
$queryURL = "xyz"
$apiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $queryURL -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
```

Comment: By calling the variable `$apiResponse` you should be able to see the contents of your get request in the Powershell host (the blue screen if using ISE or the terminal emulator if using vsCode and so on)

Comment: [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript)?

Comment: Variable `$item` is not in your script code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the `Invoke-RestMethod` to the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet, this will convert the output into an object you can easily query:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1

`$j = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.github.com/repos/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues' | ConvertFrom-Json`

Calling `$j` will output the object created from the JSON.

Comment: Invoke-Restmethod converts json to object, Invoke-Webrequest returns the regular (text) content. So you don't have to pipe the output from Invoke-RestMethod to Convertfrom-Json.